# How to make state and component the same same value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I learning design ui with react library. But I don't know what happended in my code.

```js
  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      quantity: this.state.quantity + 1
    });
    console.log(this.state);
    document.getElementsByClassName("Counter-Order")[0].innerHTML++;
  };

  handleDecrement = () => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      quantity: this.state.quantity > 1 ? this.state.quantity - 1 : 1
    });
    if (this.state.quantity > 1) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("Counter-Order")[0].innerHTML--;
    }
  };
```

Result image
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the problem is, and what the expected behavior would be?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: setState executes in like batching  so when you put a log after the setState you won't be able to see the updated value instead of that you can this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      quantity: this.state.quantity + 1
    }, () => console.log(this.state));

Comment: @Tuan Instead of adding the image, Try to explain the problem in the question itself. Much polite.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I did it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look I hope it's helpful

Thanks

```
 handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      quantity: this.state.quantity + 1
    },()=>{
     console.log(this.state);
     document.getElementsByClassName("Counter-Order")[0].innerHTML++;
    });

  };

  handleDecrement = () => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      quantity: this.state.quantity > 1 ? this.state.quantity - 1 : 1
    },()=>{
      if (this.state.quantity > 1) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("Counter-Order")[0].innerHTML--;
      }
    });

  };
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. You saved me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your welcome .. if it's useful for you then upvote or approve that answer, it makes helpful for others as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behaviour. The set state updates the state after the function has executed since it's an asynchronous function. 
So actually what happens is.

1. The setState is called.
2. Console log happens.
3. State updates.

So to check the state after setState use the 2nd parameter (callback) in the set state.

```
    this.setState(
      { ...this.state, 
       quantity: this.state.quantity + 1 }, 
      () => console.log(this.state
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are violating the main idea of React by directly accessing DOM like `document.getElementsByClassName("Counter-Order")[0].innerHTML++;`

Ideally You should have something like this in your render function.

```
render() {
   return <div className="Counter-Order">{this.state.quantity}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setState is an asynchronous function.

React internally waits for the best moment to change the state and re-render the component.

So the new state value isn't available immediatly after executing setState. That's why in your case your console.log still shows the previous state value.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You didn't make me waste my time too much. And thank you so much.